# Visual Studio 2017 Blazor Project Templates Missing

Tags: visual-studio, templates, blazor

I'm exploring building a Blazor SPA app for a test project I'm working on using Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.4). I have [installed](https://blazor.net/docs/get-started.html) .NET Core 2.2.1 and the [Blazor Language Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aspnet.blazor) but when I open Visual Studio to create a new project, no Blazor template is shown. I was able to create a project using the CLI but when I open the project in Visual Studio it gives several errors inside even though the project runs. There are also no Blazor page templates available when I try to New Item. What can I do to get the templates to load in Visual Studio?

[image: Visual Studio New Project]

[image: Errors with new Project]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. I went to File >> New >> Project, selected "ASP.Net Core Web Application" then on the next window I had to change "ASP.NET Core 2.2" to "ASP.NET Core 2.1", then the templates were there.

[image]

[image: Showing Template]

Comment: I have the same issue but this solution does not seem like it's working any more.