# Missing Blazor template in VS 2017 .Net core 2.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 with version 15.9.7 and .Net core 2.2 and .Net SDK 2.2.1. I was trying to create a `blazor` web application following [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt833288). In the article, it shows a template of type Blazor. But I do not get the same template in my visual studio.

On further investigation, I found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) but the prerequisites include Visual Studio 2019 Preview and SDK 3.0 preview. I do not want to jump to them immediately when the versions are still in preview.

So is there no way to get the template in my current configuration? Are there any kind of work around for this?

[This is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54259887/visual-studio-2017-blazor-project-templates-missing) the exact same question but the solution marked does not work in my case.

EDIT 1: I tried installing [blazor extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aspnet.blazor), but it says this extension is not installable on any currently installed products(in my case it is VS 2017).

EDIT 2 : I tried to create the project using CLI, but ended with the error

> error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli 0.9.0-preview3-19154-02 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli 0.9.0-preview3-19154-02 supports: netcoreapp3.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0)

Comment: Make sure that you have the [blazor extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aspnet.blazor) installed, and if that doesn't work, I'm afraid you need to "bite the bullet" and use VS2019 and .Net Core 3.0. Both of which are very much usable with VS2019 being released April 2nd and .Net Core 3.0 later this year

Comment: @MindSwipe I tried installing that, but it says this extension is not installable on any currently installed products(in my case it is VS 2017).

Comment: From what I have read it is only available in VS2019 and .Net Core SDK 3.0, this is what i followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The Blazor extension is what actually makes you be able to create and run Blazor apps, without it you won't be able to use Blazor. So I guess you need to either use VS2019 or wait until Blazor isn't experimental anymore

Comment: @DavidYenglin I have seen examples like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt833288 which used .Net core 2.1. Has something changed from that to it's current state?

Comment: I built a blazor project using visual studio 2017 15.9.3 and was able to install the blazor extension in my version of visual studio although this was with .net core 2.1 but I'd doubt that matters.

Comment: @GregH When was this done? I have seen many results before Jan 2019 working fine, but it seems to have changed recently

Comment: @The_Outsider It sounds like the newer versions of blazor may require vs 2019/.net core 3.. i believe my project was built using blazor v0.7 and it was built probably 4-6 months ago. sorry i cant be of more help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use Blazor you will need to upgrade to Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Core 3 preview SDK.

Before VS 2019 all the tooling for building Blazor projects was included in the Blazor Extension for Visual Studio, along with the templates. However, the tooling is now built into VS 2019 directly. The Blazor Extension now only contains project templates.

The good news is that you can install VS 2019 along side any existing stable VS versions you have. The same goes for the preview SDKs of .NET Core.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that VS 2019 is very stable and mature already (rightfully so, as it releases in a few days) and that the .Net Core 3.0 preview is also quite stable. Also, if you're considering using Blazor (an experimental web framework) then you should have no problem using preview tooling to develop it

Comment: Might be a totally wrong understanding on my part, but say I have an existing 2017 ASP.Net Core application that I need to integrate with this blazor app, Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: Not without moving to Core 3 and VS 2019. Just to be clear you're using client-side (Blazor) not server-side (Razor Components)?

Comment: Currently I have a totally functioning .Net core application which uses JS  for certain client side validation. I was thinking of a way to eliminate that by having a common server and client side code for those validations and that is where I am thinking to include Blazor.

Comment: Cool, just in case you're not aware Blazor is only experiential and could be dropped, although very unlikely. Have you looked at Razor Components (aka server-side Blazor). This is an official product in .NET Core 3. Apologies if I'm telling you things you already know.